# FATFS: file name variable in f_open function

Tags: c, fatfs

I have question regarding using variable as file name in f_open function.

`f_readdir (&mydir, &sdfileinfo)`

Once `f_readdir` is run in debug mode, I can see my file name in `fname`, but I am not sure how to use file name stored in `fname` in `f_open` function.

I tried to run `sdfileinfo.fname` as second argument in `f_open` but FR_NOFILE results.

Please see the code below

```
f_mount(&SDFatFS, "0:", 1) ;
f_opendir (&mydir, "0:/test") ;
f_readdir (&mydir, &sdfileinfo) ;
f_open(&SDFile,sdfileinfo.fname , FA_READ |FA_OPEN_EXISTING  ) ;
```

[image]

Edit1:
Please note t123.txt is file under directory test. When I run
`f_open(&SDFile, "0:/test/t123.txt", FA_READ)` it runs successfully

Comment: `sdfileinfo.fname` should work; could you show the actual code where you tried to use it? Are you sure it's a file, not a subdirectory etc? See also the [example code](http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/doc/readdir.html)

Comment: @Clifford "code in total" is often misunderstood by new users, and answered correctly with "too long". What would help is a [mre].

Comment: It would make sense to post the `f_open()` calling code.  In fact it would make sense to post code showing the `f_readdir()` and the `f_open()` in context (i.e. with all associated code and variable declarations/assignments.  Have you tried hard-coding the file name string to see if you get the same error (discounting the variable itself as an issue)?  Is it a sub-directory, because `fname` is not the full path, you would need to append it to the directory path or use `f_chdir ()` to change the _current working directory_.

Comment: t123.txt is file under directory test

Answer (score 3):

Neither `f_opendir` or `f_readdir` change the *[current working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory)*, which will be `0:/` by default.  So you are attempting to open `0:/t123.txt` rather than `0:/test/t123.txt`.

You need to include the path in the filename or set the cwd.

Using CWD:

```
f_chdir( "0:/test" ) ; // Set CWD to the target directory
f_open( &SDFile, sdfileinfo.fname, FA_READ | FA_OPEN_EXISTING ) ;
```

Or construct the full path (less safe and less efficient):

```c
char path[64] = "0:/test/" ;
strcat( path, sdfileinfo.fname ) ;
f_open( &SDFile, path, FA_READ | FA_OPEN_EXISTING ) ;
```

Comment: thank u very much... !! it worked now.. I was thinking once i run f_opendir i m already in the directory..thank you very much for your time....

Comment: @NN I can see why you might assume that.  The documentation is not clear on what is meant by "opening" a directory, but it only states that it creates a dir object for `f_readdir`.

Comment: @NN : Gentle reminder for new users. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.  Last paragraph in particular.

Comment: @Clifford What are you referring to when you say that the second option is less safe and efficient? Is it just the string concatenation/risk of buffer overflow or is it something within the FATFS?

Comment: @nielsen : Well you have an opportunity for  a buffer overrun; I have no idea how long a path might be in this case, or if the target is using LFN support.  Then there is the requirement for a buffer at all - the chdir method requires no additional memory.  Then there is of course the fact that [`strcat` is fundamentally inefficient](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/).  Clearly no an issue with fatfs, since there are no additional fatfs calls that aren't in the original code or the chdir method.  But where the full path is required for other purposes, you might do that.